# LVM in my LUN to mount

Tags: linux, lvm

i have a LUN connect to my server in this situation:

fdisk /dev/mapper/mpathg
WARNING: fdisk GPT support is currently new, and therefore in an experimental phase. Use at your own discretion.
Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.23.2).

Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

Comando (m per richiamare la guida): p

Disk /dev/mapper/mpathg: 68.7 GB, 68719476736 bytes, 134217728 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 32768 bytes / 32768 bytes
Disk label type: gpt
Disk identifier: 0CD9B4F8-3707-4E10-A1A6-D7CEBB9E99C6

```
     Start          End    Size  Type            Name
```

1         2048       411647    200M  EFI System      EFI System Partition

2       411648      2508799      1G  Microsoft basic

3      2508800    133380095   62,4G  Linux LVM

ok,so i've a LVM partition. But if i Mount it this is a result:

[root@xxx dev]# mount /dev/mapper/mpathg3 /mnt
mount: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'

how can i Mount this partition? i've already installet lvm on my server with a volume Group and a logical volumer already running

thanx
Sergio

Comment: You've only created an underlying chunk of storage suitable to be used with LVM.  You now need to create a physical volume, assign it to a volume group and create a logical volume in that volume group.  You then create a filesystem of whatever type you want on that logical volume.  Or you could just recreate partition 3 with a type suitable for you want.  But in most cases, using LVM is highly recommended.  IF YOU HAVE VALUABLE DATA ON PARTITION 3 (OR ARE UNCERTAIN) BACK IT UP IF NECESSARY BEFORE DOING ANYTHING.

Comment: hi Brandon, on  LVM partition i've data on it. so i need to mount this partition, copy some files from this, and then umount LVM partition.

Comment: Try an 'lvs' or 'lvscan' to see if the system recognizes any existing logical volumes - if so, that's what you should be working with rather than mpathg3.  If not, you may need to backtrack thru the process with a vgscan/vgs and pvscan/pvs to understand the state your lvm is in.

Comment: partition over lun is not a good idea

Answer (score 1):

1. Scan for volume groups

   lvm vgscan -v
2. Activate all Volume Groups

   lvm vgchange -y
3. List Logical Volumes

   lvm lvs -all
4. You have now activated the volumes and have all the information you need to mount them

   mkdir /mnt/your-mount-point

   mount /dev/volumegroup/logical-volume /mnt/your-mount-point